# cakephp: get textbox value in controller through postlink

Tags: php, cakephp, post, cakephp-2.0

i have a textbox and i wish to use the value entered in the textbox in controller- onclick of a link(not form submit). So i assume i have to use postlink to submit. But how do i get the value of that textbox in postlink?
following is my code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(
            'Get Coords',
            array('action' => 'test', $this->request->data['Rideoffer']['PickFrom'])
            );
        ?>
```

i get an error on `$this->request->data['Rideoffer']['PickFrom']`. data['Rideoffer']['PickFrom'] is name of my cakephp textbox(i saw it in firfox inspect element).
How do i get the textbox value?

Comment: why dont you submit the form, containg the textbox, using javascript on click on the text.

Answer (score 0):

The `FormHelper::postLink` method has no way of getting a textbox value.  The `postLink` method pretty much just creates an `<a>` link element that submits a hidden form using Javascript.  Here is an example of what `postLink` spits out:

```
<form action="/posts/delete/16" name="post_511c870e05d25" id="post_511c870e05d25" style="display:none;" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm(&#039;Are you sure you want to delete # 16?&#039;)) { document.post_511c870e05d25.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">Delete</a>
```

As you can see, when you click the `<a>` element, it submits the form with the hidden input.  You can change the value of what this input submits by passing in parameters to `postLink`, but you cannot dynamically get a value of a textbox that a user can modify and submit it with the form without doing something extra.

There are two similar options (one being slightly more Javascript heavy):

1) Since you are using Javascript, you can use Javascript (or jQuery) to dynamically change the value of the hidden input to whatever the user types.  Even better, you can do it so the Javascript/jQuery only updates the hidden form input when the user clicks the link.  Note it may be easier to not even use the `postLink` function and do all the form stuff yourself (or with Cake's FormHelper).

2) Don't use the `postLink` method at all.  Create a normal form with the textbox input and mimic what `postLink` does.  Specifically, you wouldn't have a submit button for your form.  You would just basically just copy what it spits out.

```
<form action="test" name="UNIQUE_ID" id="UNIQUE_ID" method="post">
<input type="text" name="data[RideOffer][PickFrom]" value="POST"/>
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm(&#039;This will submit the form.&#039;)) { document.UNIQUE_ID.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">Click</a>
```

Note in the above example you should match `UNIQUE_ID` as the same value and you must also remove `style="display:none;"` from the `<form>` tag.

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you explain the 1st option in detail i mean how do i write that javascript that updates the hidden field and how do i pass that hidden field to post link?

Comment: i mean in cakephp how do i bind that textbox to javascript?